# Sorting a list of string by descending order using `key` argument without `reverse=True`?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

I have a list like this one:

```
fruits = ["blueberry", "peach", "applepine", "orange", "pear", "coconut", "lemon"]
```

I need to sort it according to the following rules:

- Fruits which name contains 5 or less letters come first
- Then, fruits are ordering in reverse alphabetical order

This should give the following list:

```
sorted_fruits = ["pear", "peach", "lemon", "orange", "coconut", "blueberry", "applepine"]
```

I want to apply a reverse alphabetical sort on a list containing strings but I can not use the optional parameter `reverse=True` because this condition comes second in my sorting priorities, so I have to use a lambda function and the `key` argument.

How could I handle this?

I know that usually we can negate the `int` but I do not know the trick for `string` object, (I though to `[-ord(i) for i in fruit]` but it looks ugly).

Comment: The order of fruits whose name contains 5 or less letters does not matter?

Comment: How about the `reversed` function?

Comment: @AnandSKumar They should be reversed alphabetically too.

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply sort twice?

Comment: @DSM An "optimized" solution in terms of performance would be more interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can "artificially" reverse the first part of the key, so that using `reverse=True` gives the desired result:

```
sort_key = lambda f: ( len(f)<=5, f )
sorted(fruits, key = sort_key, reverse = True)
```

The condition `len(f)<=5` gives 0 (=False) for long strings, and 1 (=True) for short strings, so long strings come before short ones. Then, `reverse=True` corrects that.

--
For example:

```
fruits = ["blueberry", "peach", "applepine", "orange", "pear", "coconut", "lemon"]
sort_key = lambda f: ( len(f)<=5, f )
sorted(fruits, key = sort_key, reverse = True)
=> ['pear', 'peach', 'lemon', 'orange', 'coconut', 'blueberry', 'applepine']
```

Comment: @DSM, can you explain why? seems to be working on the example provided

Comment: somehow a test case I tried consistently gave the wrong answer, and I now can't reproduce it, so it was probably PEBKAC. :-)

Comment: I did not thought to this, this is smart. I am not sure that it works in all cases (a list containing tuples of three string to be ordered normally or reversed alternately for example) but it works very well with the simple examples as I gave, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a sort of mergesort by splitting off anything shorter than 5 characters, sorting each piece and them combining them into a single list.